# How to rename a file based on the directory name

Tags: linux, shell, fedora

I have a number of image files and one .mp4 in a folder. The location of these files is something like

```
directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/
```

I want to change the name of that .mp4 from "output.mp4" to something like

```
directory2_directory3_directory4.mp4
```

I'd love to have a quick way to do this without having to write out each directory name.

Comment: Can you show us what you're tried please?

Comment: Using *which* shell? `bash`?